# com/google/common/cache/RemovalCause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring-boot, guava

I'm using google guava for caching, the runtime is able to find all the classes in the jar except the RemovalCause, i have checked that the class exists in the jar using jar -tf, even redeployed to avoid jar corruption scenario. But still not able to figure what's wrong in this?

```
threw exception com/google/common/cache/RemovalCause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/cache/RemovalCause
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.expireEntries(LocalCache.java:2595) ~[guava-30.1-jre.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.runLockedCleanup(LocalCache.java:3452) ~[guava-30.1-jre.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.preWriteCleanup(LocalCache.java:3434) ~[guava-30.1-jre.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.put(LocalCache.java:2774) ~[guava-30.1-jre.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.put(LocalCache.java:4181) ~[guava-30.1-jre.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.put(LocalCache.java:4865) ~[guava-30.1-jre.jar:?]
```

Comment: How are you creating the jar? Through maven?

Comment: @Renis1235 yes, but how is that related ?

Comment: Each Building tool has different configurations. Are you able to run your program in your IDE? And what is your IDE?

Comment: Does one of your dependencies pull in Guava? Guava is notorious for having breaking changes.

Comment: @Renis1235 yes able to run in intellij ide

Comment: @David Ehrmann , sorry didn't get you. What do you mean by "dependencies pull in Guava" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try building a fat Jar with IntelliJ and put all the dependencies in it.

This is the way:

1. Go to Project Settings & Artifacts `File-> Project Structure... -> Artifacts`
2. Click in the `+` Button to add an artifact
3. Choose `JAR -> From Module With dependencies`
4. Choose your `Main` class through the `folder` button
5. Click in the created Artifact you will have something like this:

[image: Screenshot]

6. Select all the elements in the right and right click and then put into the output root
7. Make sure you have copied all Available elements to your jar.
8. A META-INF Folder is created at your project root, copy that to your resources folder.
9. Click `Build` in the context menu above and then build artifacts and then build your artifact.

Good luck!

Comment: currently a thin jar is being created and all jars are copied to the lib directory from where it could be referenced. All other jars are working properly , even this one, but just having issue with one class RemovalCause. Changing deployment strategy is handled by another team, hence cannot be changed. Even though, since other jars aren't facing this issue, i believe build not to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

found that, the issue was happening when the application is either coming up/down and the server is tomcat. Similar issues on tomcat are being reported that static classes or enums are offloaded by the classloader during boot up or when app goes down. Also, as most frameworks like spring will stop taking rest-requests when application is going down, so, the issue is likely to occur only for messaging subscriptions (kafka or similar) or scheduled jobs.